# Почему matplotlib автоматически сортирует значения по возрастанию в списке?

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, график

В **первый контейнер** добавляю три значения:

```
L = float(2.2)
list_of_fluxex = []
list_of_current = []


def input_current():
    """
    функция принимает и сохраняет значения тока
    :return: список значений тока (до 3 включительно)
    """
    count = 0
    while count < 3:
        x = input(f"Введите значение тока №{count + 1}: ")
        count += 1
        list_of_current.append(float(x))
    return list_of_current
```

После вызова функции заполняю **второй контейнер**:

```
for all_fluxex in range(len(list_of_current)):
    flux = round(list_of_current[all_fluxex] * L, 2)
    list_of_fluxex.append(flux)
```

И несмотря на **ЛЮБЫЕ** значения, matplotlib создаёт исключительно **возрастающий график**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from main2 import list_of_current, list_of_fluxex


current = [list_of_current[0], list_of_current[1], list_of_current[2]]

flux = [list_of_fluxex[0], list_of_fluxex[1], list_of_fluxex[2]]

plt.plot(current, flux, marker="o")

plt.xlabel("current")
plt.ylabel("flux")

plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но стоит в значения вписать любые цифры, всё показывается как надо. Как такое возможно?

```
current = [5, 2, 9]

flux = [15, 12, 6]
```

[image]

Comment: Или я чего не понимаю, или где у вас в основной программе оказывается вызов   input_current () ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу passant покажу в общем-то тоже самое, но другими словами и средствами.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

current = [2, 3, 1]
flux = [2.2*x for x in current]

plt.plot(current, flux, marker="o")

for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(current, flux), 1):
    plt.text(x - 0.05, y + 0.1, i, c='red')

plt.xlabel("current")
plt.ylabel("flux")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этом графике обозначены шаги построения графика. Да, получается, что если следовать по точкам по очереди, то график не только возрастает от точки 1 до точки 2, но и падает от точки 2 к точке 3. Проблема в том, что все точки расположены на одной линии из-за того, что ваша функция линейная, вида `y = x * 2.2`. И точки на осях всегда рисуются отсортированными, иначе какой вообще смысл в графиках на координатах, если по осям будут произвольные значения в произвольном порядке. Вот и получается в итоге, что да - график всегда возрастает, вне зависимости от порядка рисования точек, но это в точности отражает природу вашей функции - все её точки расположены на одной прямой линии, поэтому у неё и должен быть график в виде одной прямой линии с несколькими точками на ней.

Comment: Теперь моя очередь дополнять уважаемого CrazyElf.  " какой вообще смысл в графиках на координатах, если по осям будут произвольные значения в произвольном порядке." - такие задачи могут встречаться, например, если вам надо не просто отобразить двумерные точки, но и отобразить их в порядке их поступления.  Правда, тогда надо использовать другой тип графика. current = [5, 2, 9]
current = list(map( str, current  ))
flux = [15, 12, 14]
plt.scatter(current, flux, s=100)

Comment: @passant Тут вы, уважаемый, на самом деле превратили числа в категориальные значения. Да, так можно, и резон в этом действительно есть. Но когда переменная по своей природе числовая, то как-то это запутывающе выглядит на графике, мне кажется. Впрочем, я пока не настоящий дата-сайентист, ещё много чего, наверное, не встречал в своей практике )

Answer (score 1):

Ну и запутали вы всех :-).
Даже интересно стало, но поскольку я в чудеса не верю, пришлось сделать расследование и вывести "вас на чистую воду".
Ну, сначала находим нужное место для input_current (), конечно. Потом вводим три числа. Пусть они буду ваши же current = [5, 2, 9].

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь вводим ваш второй пример. current = [5, 2, 9] и flux = [15, 12, 6]. И видим на экране то, что вы нам и представили.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но мы же не верим в чудеса. И берем другой пример current = [5, 2, 9] и flux = [11.0, 4.4, 19.8]. И увы, все чудеса улетучиваются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Оказывается, что plt.plot() работает как надо, рисует в том порядке, что вы и задали. Вот только в вашем первом примере все данные лежат на прямой, поскольку вы генерировали свой второй массив как линейную функцию

> list_of_current[all_fluxex] * L

и увидеть, в каком порядке точки наносились на график не могли. А во втором вашем примере - задавали произвольные точки. Вот и "проявился" порядок их нанесения.

Но головоломка оказалась знатная. И для программиста - очень полезная. Я всегда говорю, что отлаживать программу и умение находить в ней ошибки на много важнее, чем умение просто кодировать.